# How to remove page element from search results / keywords?

Tags: html, search-engine, seo

Problem is here. I have simple page with form and not so much other text content. In form I have for example:

```
        <h1>It should be my search result</h1>
        <form>
    <select name="Months">
          <option>January</option>
          <option>February</option>
...
          <option>December</option>
    </select>
        </form>
```

In search results/page keywords I have more months names than other important content, where keywords should be IT SHOULD BE MY SEARCH RESULT only. How I can disable select content from results? Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repositioning the code (as mentioned in the other answer) does work when you're trying to prioritize content on the markup level. However, it doesn't take care of the keyword density of the month names you want to suppress.

If your page is littered with multiple dropdowns with the same 12 months in them; you could use Javascript to add the dropdowns after the page is done loading. It will suppress it from Google Crawlers while also leaving it in for site visitors. Of course, too much Javascript will be a performance hit.

(Note: on a SEO level, Google doesn't like when you show Google a different page than what would be shown to a site visitor; but I don't think this would hurt you).

If your month names are literally inside the search results content, you could try using server side code (PHP, ASP.NET, etc.) to filter out the month names entirely or replacing them with ellipses; though, may be confusing

It really depends on what your results page would look like. More information would be needed to get a better idea on the best way to tackle it.

Comment: Thank you. This java script solution should be best here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article on 4 ways to hide content from Google

http://www.searchenginejournal.com/4-ways-to-hide-content-from-google-and-googles-reaction/6782/

I would use the option of moving the navigation to the bottom of your code and then reposition it with CSS so that it appears in the location you want. Then from the user's perspective it will appear at the top, and from Google's perspective appear at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

No guarantee that this would work (it might be viewed as deceiving the bot), but try to split the months into meaningless parts by `<wbr>`.

```
<select name="Months">
      <option>Ja<wbr>nuary</option>
      <option>Fe<wbr>bru<wbr>ary</option>
...
      <option>Dece<wbr>mber</option>
</select>
```